# Google Calendars API - Listener for new calendar events or updates to existing events?

Tags: python, google-calendar-api

I have a Python script that will take all of the events from a Google Calendar, format the text and send a post request to a website, which works fine.

Currently, I would have to open it each time an event is added or changed. I am wondering how can I setup a listener so that the function will fire whenever there are new calendar events or updates to existing ones? I have looked into the documentation but have not been able to find any good solution.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should make use of the webhooks to listen to any updates in the events. Read here, https://developers.google.com/calendar/v3/push