# Listener for Google Events

Tags: google-calendar-api

This other question suggested using webhooks to listen for an event. [Google Calendars API - Listener for new calendar events or updates to existing events?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60406976/google-calendars-api-listener-for-new-calendar-events-or-updates-to-existing-e)

As the admin, I need to listen for new, updated or deleted events **in all my users calendars**. Once alerted then I will take the event information and then do something with it in another business software application.

How can I use the webhook to not just listen for a events in a single user's calendar but in all calendars?

Answer (score 1):

You have to create a resource for each Calendar. You can do it using the Directory API to fetch all the users and their respective Calendars:

1. [List](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/reference/users/list) all the users in your domain.
2. Get the **primary email** of each user, which is also their Calendar Id.
3. Use a for loop to iterate over the emails and make a [POST](https://developers.google.com/calendar/v3/push#example) request:
   `POST https://www.googleapis.com/calendar/v3/calendars/my_calendar@gmail.com/events/watch`

If this is not feasible, you can request this feature on Google's [Issue Tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues?q=componentid:191627%2B).